# Use a font style different from defaults on vb.net

Tags: vb.net, fonts, barcode, font-size, code39

I'm developing a program in vb.net. The problem is when i'm building an image using DrawString from Graphics and put it into a picturebox. The font i'm using is Free 3 of 9 for Code39 barcode coding. The code build using font style "Normal" is not readable from scanner, but it is readable when i use font style "Expanded".

Now the problem in vb.net is that i cannot select font styles different from:
-Normal
-Italic
-Bold
-Underlined
-Strikeout

I tried everyone, but nothing happened. If you have a solution, please, write here.

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You'll probably have to use a different method to create and draw your font.

Comment: You are trying to solve the wrong problem.  The most common issue is the rescaling that takes place when a bitmap is printed with, say, the PrintDocument class.  Printers are very high resolution devices, one pixel in the bitmap turns into a 6x6 blob on paper.  You simply need to make the bitmap 6 times bigger and use a 6 times bigger font.  And draw it 6 times smaller.  You'll get a razor-sharp printout, barcode scanners like that.